# Tumblr SDK(or Sharekit) for Android, does it exist?

Tags: android, sdk, tumblr

I need to integrate Tumblr to my Android app, is there any official(I could not find) or 3rd party SDK available?

Thanks!

edit:

I found ShareKit is a good tool for sharing purpose on iOS, is there any equivalent in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to enable sharing in an Android app is to use the ACTION_SEND intent. This will let the user share the content to any compatible app they may have installed.

Comment: But what if the user do not have compatible app installed, for example, Tumblr client?

Comment: If the user doesn't have a tumblr app installed, it's highly likely that they are not a tumblr user and are not interested in a button for that service cluttering the UI of their other apps. :)

Comment: How can i share a link to tumblr post via ACTION_SEND

Answer (score 1):

Using ACTION_SEND intent is the easiest way, but I loose all control under sharing process: I have not control under list of applications for sharing, I can't customize anything. And main problem is each app can have traits of sharing process. For example Facebook app shares **only** http links and ignores anything other. In some my projects I use SDK for each social network to avoid this problems e.g. [facebook sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, adamp is right. You can use the ACTION_SEND intent.
For more information see [this Example](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-sending-pictures-the-easy-way/) to Share the Photo among available Application in Android Device.